# Refactor method that combines an array of strings into a sentence

Tags: ruby, arrays, refactoring

I'm writing a method to combine an array of strings and integers into a sentence. It has to capitalize the first letter, add spaces between the words, and put a period at the end. Here's how I wrote it:

```
def sentence_maker(y)
  y[0].capitalize!
  y[-1]="#{y[-1]}."
  sentence = y.join(" ")
end
```

Here's an example of an array that would get passed:

```
["alaska", "has", "over", 586, "thousand", "miles"]
```

What would be a refactor of this method?
Thanks in advance for the help. Ruby 2.1.1p76

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refactoring, which should be asked on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this?:

```
words = ["alaska", "has", "over", 586, "thousand", "miles"]
words.join(' ').strip.capitalize << '.' #=> "Alaska has over 586 thousand miles."
```

or with string interpolation:

```
"#{words.join(' ').strip.capitalize}." #=> "Alaska has over 586 thousand miles."
```

`strip` will remove leading/trailing whitespace in string(if there are any in first or last values of array).

**UPDATE**: You can wrap this as array's instance method:

```
class Array
  def to_sentence
    "#{join(' ').strip.capitalize}."
  end
end

words = ["alaska", "has", "over", 586, "thousand", "miles"]
words.to_sentence # => "Alaska has over 586 thousand miles."
```

Comment: how did you get the period on the last value of the array?

Comment: Sorry about that, was testing some code when I posted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code a whole lot readable:

```
def sentence_maker(array)
  array.first.capitalize!
  array.last.concat('.')
  array.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: Um I don't see a space before the period. Using Ruby 2.0 here.

Comment: @daremkd : assume the last value has: `"miles "` instead of `"miles"`, you'll have to remove that whitespace before concatenating `'.'` then.